# Get the current value of env.hosts list with Python Fabric Library

Tags: python, fabric

I've got this code (`foo` and `bar` are local servers):

```
env.hosts = ['foo', 'bar']

def mytask():
    print(env.hosts[0])
```

Which, of course prints *foo* every iteration.

As you probably know, Fabric iterates through the env.hosts list and executes mytask() on each of them this way:

```
fab mytask
```

does

`task` is executed on `foo`
`task` is executed on `bar`

I'm looking for a way to get the **current host** in every iteration.

Thanks,

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use `env.host_string`. You can find a full list of `env` variables [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/env.html#full-list-of-env-vars).

Comment: Note that host_sting will have any extra connection info, if used, of the username and port, instead of the plain hostname.

Answer (score 27):

You can just do:

```
env.hosts = ['foo', 'bar']

def mytask():
     print(env.host)
```

Because when you're in the task as executed by fab, you'll have that var set for free.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Marcelo.

If you want to actually use `env.host_string` (for concatenation purpose for instance), be sure to be inside a task. Its value is `None` outside.